# Add comments to XML based on attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xpath and xsl and have a question. How can I add comments to the beginning and ending of each node on the XML based on an attribute of the node? For example in the below input the id:num is my attribute with value A. Any nodes in my xml can have the attribute id:num with value as A and in front of every node with the attribute id:num="A" i need to add comment as shown in the expected output section. Please help!

Example input xml:

```
<rootNode id:num="A">
</child nodes>
</rootNode>
```

Expected Output:

```
<!--comment--><rootNode id:num="A">
</child nodes>
</rootNode>
<!--comment-->
```

I am confused as how to implement the same as I'm unsure how to check the attribute value on the xsl:template match expression

Comment: You want to add the same comment before _and_ after the element with the matching attribute? By the way, your sample XML is not well-formed because it contains an attribute `id:num` whose name contains a namespace prefix `id`, but there's no namespace declaration with that prefix e.g. `xmlns:id='http://example.com/id"`

Comment: The XSLT specification includes a section on template match patterns with examples of how to match various things, including elements with particular attribute values: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#patterns

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: The sample given is not a proper xml and is just an illustration to explain my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to check the attribute value on the xsl:template match expression

You can use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates):

```
<xsl:template match="rootNode[@id:num='A']">
```

(This is the only part of your question I understood. There may be other ways to solve the underlying problem.)